# A View which displays Posts assigned to a Parent which is followed by current user

Tags: views, entities, flags

A little advice please:

Users "follow" a content type Parent by using the method [in this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/43797/9703). There is a content type Posts which has an Entity Reference to the Parent it is assigned to.

How do I go about creating a View which shows all Posts which the current user has "followed"?

I guess this could be done with [Views Field View](http://drupal.org/project/views_field_view) but that seems a little over-kill. There must be a simpler way of doing this, just with Views out-the-box, surely?

### Update

[See my answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/48598/9703). Please, *please*, if anybody has a better solution let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Use Views PHP.

In Views

- Format

  - Content
- Filter Criteria

  - Content: Published
  - Content: Type (=Post)
  - Global: PHP (see below for code)

Code for Global: PHP -

```
$flag = flag_get_flag('follow_parent');

$post_nid = $data->nid;

$post = node_load($post_nid);

$field_parent = field_get_items('node',$post,'field_parents');

$parents_followeds = array();

foreach ($field_parents as $field_parent) {
  $parent_nid = $field_parent['target_id'];
  $followed = $flag->is_flagged($parent_nid);
  $parent_followeds[] = $followed;
}

return in_array(TRUE, $parent_followeds) ? FALSE : TRUE;
```